# async/await inside arrow functions (Array#map/filter)

Tags: javascript, async-await, ecmascript-2017

I'm getting compile time error in this code:

```
const someFunction = async (myArray) => {
    return myArray.map(myValue => {
        return {
            id: "my_id",
            myValue: await service.getByValue(myValue);
        }
    });
};
```

Error message is:

> await is a reserved word

Why can't I use it like this?

Comment: I don't think you can have async arrow functions.

Comment: Relevant https://github.com/tc39/ecmascript-asyncawait/issues/7

Comment: To summarize from the linked github discussion, you can't do that because the anonymous function you're passing as a callback is not `async` and the inner `await` can't affect the outer function.

Comment: `async/await` is part of ES2017 (this year's release), not ES7 (last year's release).

Answer (score 207, accepted):

You can't do this as you imagine, because you can't use `await` if it is not directly inside an `async` function.

The sensible thing to do here would be to make the function passed to `map` asynchronous. This means that `map` would return an array of promises. We can then use `Promise.all` to get the result when all the promises return. As `Promise.all` itself returns a promise, the outer function does not need to be `async`.

```
const someFunction = (myArray) => {
    const promises = myArray.map(async (myValue) => {
        return {
            id: "my_id",
            myValue: await service.getByValue(myValue)
        }
    });
    return Promise.all(promises);
}
```

Comment: in this case array of promises is not slower that  classic for let in array ?

Comment: @stackdave Probably, but the difference will  be inconsequential next to `service.getByValue`, which may well involve a network call...

Comment: thanks I've start using it, anyway readibility is better than velocity, because most of ES6 async techniques always will be slower, but who care

Comment: @lonesomeday Can this handle errors or throttling/delays between calls?

Comment: @KylePennell Yes. You'd need to handle errors either with a `try..catch` in the async function or with a `catch` handler before returning from the outer function. A throttle could be introduced before the `return` in the async function.

Comment: Good note would be to specify you need to put `await` in front of `Promise.all`, but here since is directly returned it's not needed since return does `await` for you.

Comment: @Joan Albert You certainly do not need to put await in. In fact you can't as the function is not asynchronous. Promise.all simply returns a promise, which can just be returned like any JavaScript object.

Comment: @lonesomeday yes, you're right, if you want to have all the array promises solved, you would need to add the `async` like `... = async (myArray) => ...`

Comment: @Joan Albert but then the function will return a Promise, as all asynchronous functions do...

Answer (score 79):

If you want to run map with an asynchronous mapping function you can use the following code:

```
const resultArray = await Promise.all(inputArray.map(async (i) => someAsyncFunction(i)));
```

**How it works:**

- `inputArray.map(async ...)` returns an array of promises - one for each value in `inputArray`.
- Putting `Promise.all()` around the array of promises converts it into a single promise.
- The single promise from `Promise.all()` returns an array of values - the individual promises each resolve to one value.
- We put `await` in front of `Promise.all()` so that we wait for the combined promise to resolve and store the array of resolved sub-promises into the variable `resultArray`.

In the end we get one output value in `resultArray` for each item in `inputArray`, mapped through the function `someAsyncFunction`.  We have to wait for all async functions to resolve before the result is available.

Answer (score 17):

That's because the function in `map` isn't *async*, so you can't have *await* in it's return statement. It compiles with this modification:

```
const someFunction = async (myArray) => {
    return myArray.map(async (myValue) => { // <-- note the `async` on this line
        return {
            id: "my_id",
            myValue: await service.getByValue(myValue)
        }
    });
};
```

[Try it out in Babel REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&code=const%20someFunction%20%3D%20async%20(myArray)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20myArray.map(async%20(myValue)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20id%3A%20%22my_id%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20myValue%3A%20await%20service.getByValue(myValue)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%7D%3B)

So… it's not possible to give recommendation without seeing the rest of your app, but depending on what are you trying to do, either make the *inner* function asynchronous or try to come up with some different architecture for this block.

Update: we might get top-level await one day: https://github.com/MylesBorins/proposal-top-level-await

Comment: thanks, upvoted, but your code return array with empty objects (i.e. `[{}, {}]`). I think I need to include somewhere `await`, but couldn't realize where

Comment: What does the `service.getByValue` function look like?

Comment: it just returns ES6 Promise

Comment: It looks to me like the OP expects an array of id'ed objects as the final result, so in keeping with that I think you probably want `return await Promise.all(myArray.map`... for equivalency.

Answer (score 10):

it will be 2 instructions, but just shift "await" with the extra instruction

```js
let results = array.map((e) => fetch('....'))
results  = await Promise.all(results)
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried all these answers but no one works for my case because all answers return a `promise` object not the `result of the promise` like this:

```
{
  [[Prototype]]: Promise
  [[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
  [[PromiseResult]]: Array(3)
  0: ...an object data here...
  1: ...an object data here...
  2: ...an object data here...
  length: 3
  [[Prototype]]: Array(0)
}
```

Then I found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/64978715/8339172 that states if `map` function is not async or promise aware.
So instead of using `await` inside `map` function, I use `for` loop and `await` the individual item because he said that `for` loop is `async` aware and will pause the loop.

Answer (score 0):

When you want each remapped value resolved before moving on to the next, you can process the array as an asynchronous iterable.

Below, we use library [iter-ops](https://github.com/vitaly-t/iter-ops), to remap each value into promise, and then produce an object with resolved value, because `map` itself shouldn't be handling any promises internally.

```
import {pipe, map, wait, toAsync} from 'iter-ops';

const i = pipe(
    toAsync(myArray), // make asynchronous
    map(myValue => {
        return service.getByValue(myValue).then(a => ({id: 'my_id', myValue: a}))
    }),
    wait() // wait for each promise
);

(async function() {
    for await (const a of i) {
        console.log(a); // print resulting objects
    }
})
```

After each value, we use [wait](https://vitaly-t.github.io/iter-ops/functions/wait.html) to resolve each remapped value as it is generated, to keep resolution requirement consistent with the original question.