# Await keyword not working within Redux action

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, redux, async-await

I'm trying to incorporate the async/await syntax into my Redux actions but, for some reason, it's not working. I cannot for the life of me see what is wrong with the following:

```
const actions = {
    load: async (staff, date) => dispatch => {
        const data = {
            dateFrom: date,
            dateTo: date,
            person: staff,
            personType: 'staff'
        };

        const events = utils.getDataPromise('json/events/load', data);
        const classes = utils.getDataPromise('json/timetable/load', data);

        dispatch({
            type: actions.MYDAY_LOAD,
            staff,
            date: date || new Date(),
            events: await events,
            classes: await classes
        });
    },
}
```

The utils function definitely returns a promise.

Comment: are you using thunk?

Comment: @isaac Yes, I'm using thunk. The error I'm getting is with the `await` keywords -- even my IDE is telling me they are in the wrong spot.

Comment: `load` is an async function that returns a non async function, move your async before `dispatch`. Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42489918/async-await-inside-arraymap)

Comment: @Gerado Thanks, that worked perfectly. Feel free to write it in an answer and I'll mark it accepted.

Comment: Interesting. A working example I have in front of me is something like this: `export function myAction() { let value = await something(); return dispatch(value); }`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a common mistake due to arrow functions syntax.

Your `load` function is `async` but returns an anonymous arrow function `dispatch => {...}`.

`await` only works when it's inside an `async` function and your `await` calls are inside the anonymous returned function which is not `async` that's why it doesn't work. Move `async` just before `dispatch` and that should work.

```
const actions = {
    load: (staff, date) => async dispatch => {...}
    //                     ^^^^^ move it here
...
}
```