# React useEffect and iterating over array using Vimeo API

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I have an array of trying to grab four thumbnail jpgs' from using the vimeo API. I have an array of video ids

```
const vimeo = [
    "325845565","325846054","325848270","325849439"
]
```

I'm using setState to import and use the arrays

```
import vimeo;

const [data , setData ] = useState(vimeo)
```

I have a separate state where I would like to store the thumbnails data:

```
const [thumbNails, setThumbNails] = useState({
    data : []
})
```

Id like to be able to iterate over each vimeo id inside the useEffect hook. I'm using axios something like:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
        data.map(videoID => {
            const result = await axios(`http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/${data[0]}.json`);
            setThumbNails({
                data : result
            })
        }
        })

    fetchData()
},[])
```

but with this code im getting the following error:

Parsing error: Can not use keyword 'await' outside an async function

Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: Parser error aside (you've just misplaced the `async` declaration, it should be on the `data.map` callback not `fetchData`) how do you expect this code to work? At the moment it would always overwrite the last thumbnail that you fetch. Also, `result` in this case would be an axios response, I presume you'd want `data: result.data`...

Answer (score 0):

That a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42489918/async-await-inside-arraymap) and also [what I found on google](https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-async-await-array-map/)

You will need to use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) and then `setState` with the array returned

```
const fetchData = async () => {
    let fetchedResult = await Promise.all(data.map(videoID => 
        axios(`http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/${data[0]}.json`)
    ))
    fetchedResult.map(data => setThumbNails({
            data : result
        }))
}
```

Comment: Although this is syntactically correct, the map code in general looks all wrong.

Comment: @James Why `the map code in general looks all wrong` ? I copied your code and added the correct `async`.

Comment: @Vencovksy I'm not the OP (same name).

Comment: @James you got me hahaha

Comment: Thanks but I don't' think I can use the await as a parameter inside the map function BTW I am the OP :)

Comment: @James (The OP) Take a look, just edited, and you were right about that