# Invalid character found in method name error when fetching an api using React

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid-react

I have implemented a table using ag-grid react. I fetch data from an api to fill in that table.

```
const getDataForTable = async () => {
  try {
    //apis to fetch the data
    setGridData(apiData);
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
} 

useEffect(() => {
  getDataForTable();
}, []);
```

Now, I have also created an onClick method for deleting selected rows of the table. I am removing the rows from api as well. Once the rows are deleted, I just want to refresh the grid with updated data. Currently it only works if I explicitly reload the page.

```
const onClickRemoveRowsByIds = async () => {
  selectedRows.forEach(d => {
    listOfIds.push(d.Id);
  });
  if (window.confirm("Are you sure ?")) {
    await listOfIds.map((ele) => removeActiveList(ele));
    getDataForTable()
  }
}
```

But when I make a call to `getDataForTable` function, I get **bad request error** for the apis. On looking at the reponse body of the api : I get **Invalid character found in method name. HTTP method names must be tokens**. The authToken and rest of the information remains same but still fetch is not working again. Am I missing some step, or doing it completely wrong? The delete works fine, just the refresh is not happening.

Comment: Did you check your server API for why it's returning bad requests in 1st place?

Comment: What are these mutating data, like selectedRows,listOfIds?

Comment: selectedRows is a state which is updated based on the rows selected. And listOfIds is just an array

Comment: listOfIds.map() returns a new array, not sure why you have await there? If you are awaiting on removeActiveList(ele) await should be just before that.

Comment: Use a regular for loop and use await there or do like this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42489918/async-await-inside-arraymap

Comment: Regarding server apis returning bad requests --- the api request is same as previous one which was successful. It works only on page loading. When I trigger the function explicitly, it fails

Comment: use a for loop and await on removeActiveList() instead of map(). You are deleting items 1 by 1 and before finishing the operation as your await is in the wrong place, most probably your API is failing when you try to fetch something being changed.

Comment: Even without the loop it acted that way. First I tried with single row delete, even then apis threw bad request error

Comment: Not sure. Seems like there must be some difference while calling the API a second time. you may check with dev tools and use both API calls in postman and see if there is any difference.